# How to implement subclasses of PFObject subclasses?

Tags: parse-platform, subclassing

I have a subclass `A` of a Parse `PFObject` defined as (details left out):

```
@interface A : PFObject <PFSubclassing>
@end
@implementation A
+ (void)load {
    [self registerSubclass];
}
+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}
@end
```

I need a subclass `B` of `A`, defined as

```
@interface B : A <PFSubclassing>
@end
@implementation B
+ (void)load {
    [self registerSubclass];
}
+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}
@end
```

`A` and `B` are registered in the AppDelegate by

```
[A registerSubclass];
[B registerSubclass];
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to define subclasses of subclasses of `PFObject`:

https://www.parse.com/questions/what-does-this-error-mean-subclasses-of-subclasses-may-not-have-separate-parseclassname-definitions suggests that one should not define `+ (NSString *)parseClassName` in subclass `A`, only in subclass `B`.
But if I do so, I get an error `+[A parseClassName]: unrecognized selector sent to class` when `A`’s `registerSubclass` method is called.
When I also leave out the `+ (void)load` method of subclass `A`, and the call to `[A registerSubclass]` in the AppDelegate, the app seems to work.

So my question is:

Is it correct, to use only for the subclass at the lowest level `<PFSubclassing>`, `+ (NSString *)parseClassName`, `+ (void)load`, and register it in the AppDelegate, or which is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question; maybe this helps others (I have now used the following setup for 2 weeks, and everything seems to work fine):

If one has subclasses of `PFObject` subclasses, **only for the lowest subclass** in the hierarchy one has to do the following:

- Register it in the AppDelegate
- Adopt `PFSubclassing` and implement `+(void)load` and `+(NSString *)parseClassName`

Comment: Will the subclassed subclasses show up as completed different objects in the dashboard, or will they be pooled together?

Comment: @Michael Voccola They are displayed as different objects in the dashboard (this was at least the case with the original Parse dashboard).